# Renaming elastic search output fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with using elastic search at the moment.  When I try to perform a search and only want a subset of the fields returned, I need to specify the fields using a dot-notation if the fields are nested.  Here's a sample of my mapper json document which maps my couchDB document:

```
{
    "product": {
        "_type": {"store": "yes"},
        "_source": {"compress": true},
        "index_analyzer": "standard",
        "search_analyzer": "standard",
        "dynamic_date_formats": ["date_time_no_millis", "date_optional_time"],
        "properties": {
              "_id": {"type": "string", "store": "yes", "index": "not_analyzed"},
            "key": {"type": "string", "store": "yes"},
            "content": {
                "type": "object",
                "path": "just_name",
                "properties": {
                    "key": {"type": "string", "store": "yes"},
                    "name": {"type": "string", "store": "yes", "index_name": "name"},
                    "description": {"type": "string", "store": "yes", "index_name": "description"},
                    "brand": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "index_name": "brand",
                        "properties": {
                            "abbreviation": {"type": "string", "store": "yes", "index_name": "brand_abbreviation"},
                            "name": {"type": "string", "store": "yes", "index_name": "brand_name"}
                        }
                    }
                                }
                        }
                 }
          }
}
```

Referring to _id would just be a simple _id, but say I wanted to refer to name in the content, I would have to refer to it as content.name.  The problem with this is that when the search output is out, the json output contains the field name as: "content.name".

Is it possible to rename this as "name" and without the "content." prefix?  You can see, I tried to specify index_name, but that seemed useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`partial_fields`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/fields.html) to do this.

For instance, if you index a doc like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/1?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "email" : "john@foo.com",
   "name" : "john",
   "foo" : {
      "bar" : {
         "baz" : 1
      }
   }
}
'
```

You can include the fields/objects that you want like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "partial_fields" : {
      "doc" : {
         "include" : [
            "name",
            "foo.*"
         ]
      }
   }
}
'
```

Which will give you a result like this: (note the missing `email` field, and that field `foo` remains a hash - it is not flattened with dot notation)

```
{
   "hits" : {
      "hits" : [
         {
            "_score" : 1,
            "fields" : {
               "doc" : {
                  "name" : "john",
                  "foo" : {
                     "bar" : {
                        "baz" : 1
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "_index" : "test",
            "_id" : "1",
            "_type" : "test"
         }
      ],
      "max_score" : 1,
      "total" : 1
   },
   "timed_out" : false,
   "_shards" : {
      "failed" : 0,
      "successful" : 5,
      "total" : 5
   },
   "took" : 1
}
```

On a side note, some comments about your mapping:

- your `_id` field (which I assume is meant to be the elasticsearch ID, not an external ID) is at the wrong level - it should be at the same level as `_type`.  If it IS an external ID, then it's at the right level.
- Why are you storing all your fields? There really is no need - it just uses extra resources. Unless you have a massive `_source` field, it is much faster to retrieve just that field and parse it, rather than hitting the disk for each individual field.

Comment: First off I want to thank you for replying to this.  This is the first decent answer I've received with regards to elastic search to date!  Even the mailing list or the IRC channel didn't help much!  

Yes, the _id field is an external ID.  

Why am I storing all fields?  I really have no idea; it sounded like  if I don't store them, means that they won't get indexed.  Thanks for the tip.  

All in all, I feel the documentation is lacking in some real world examples or very detailed examples.  You've helped me a lot, thank you!

Comment: Um...I want to accept this answer, but could you please help me out with my comment?